# Is there a set of adjective word list for positive or negative polarity

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis. I thought if there is any available set of adjectives indicating positive/negative(like for positive: good,awesome,amazing,) meaning? and the second thing is a set of data from which i can use as a test case.

Comment: I understand that this may not be an SO question, but it was the best and simplest set of responses on my google search. I still think its a useful addition to the knowledge-base

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resources related to polarity:

SentiWordNet: http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/

Inquirer Dictionary: http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/homecat.htm

Possible test data: http://www.cs.pitt.edu/mpqa/

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of test data do you want. Do you intend to evaluate the resources? If that's the case, then consider reading their papers on how they did their evaluations.

Answer (score 6):

A list of positive and negative opinion words or sentiment words for English (around 6800 words): http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html